# Why is an LLVM JIT-generated entry point so wordy under 64-bit Windows?

Tags: windows, llvm

I'm playing around with LLVM under Windows, just trying to understand it a little better by building some sample programs. Currently, I'm looking at HowToUseJIT. I noticed that when I run 64-bit, I get an entry point with what seems to be some pretty really crazy code. It saves rsi, rdi and xmm6-xmm15 on the stack; then sets rax and rcx; then restores all of the previously-saved values before finally calling the next function in the call chain.

Is there a good reason for this? Or does it suggest that LLVM on Windows x64 is not quite ready for prime-time?

EDIT: This was with LLVM 2.8. I just downloaded what's currently on the 2.9 branch and it doesn't show the same behavior.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. All the register saves are due to Win64 ABI, when they are callee-saved and thus should be properly saved / restored.

The reason why they noop loads / stores are not eliminated is might due to fast instruction selector used by default for JIT. It will get you the binary code really fast but sacrificing the quality.

Try to switch to normal codegen to check whether the problem still exist.